# C++ passing a type that's identical to another type

Tags: c++

Could anyone answer this question?

The following code will highlight the problem better than my awkward question.

```
struct vector2d
{
    float x,y;
};

struct point2d
{
    float x, y;
}

void drawpoint(point2d point);

int main()
{
    vector2d vec = {100, 100};
    drawpoint(vec);
}

void drawpoint(point2d point)
{
    ...
}
```

I am wondering why this is not working.  The alternative is to manually transform the type via an intermediate heap point2d variable, but would the compiler see this and know that wasn't necassary?

There's probably a very simple thing I'm missing out on here, thanks in advance.

Comment: you are referring to nonexistent types such as `Void` and `Float` and giving your functions names that result in a syntax error (e. g. `Draw-point`). There's no way this code is possibly going to work. Post **real code.**

Comment: Was incorrectly capitalized `void` seriously preventing you from understanding the gist of this question?

Comment: Drawpoint did not contain a hyphen, and posting from tablet means caps are automatically managed, for better or worse.

Comment: @KayOL78: I assume that you don't program on a tablet, and people on this site like seeing some effort on the part of question posters to be willing to answer. Just so you know. :)

Comment: I know.  I was kind of hoping the part of the brain we all have that can see past strongly typed text would win out, as opposed to our inner pedantry.  However, point taken, and duly noted!

Comment: Thanks whoever compiled my code without errors!  void main() does compile however...is this nonstandard?

Comment: @KayOL78 Technically, though every compiler in the world will accept it.

Comment: @Kay: You'd be surprised how often silly, obvious things really are the problem. It is not uncommon for a person who has done something silly (like capitalizing things that shouldn't be) to be stuck in that mindset for quite a while and not recognize it as a mistake.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler is helping you out by not converting types all willy-nilly. Suppose you had a `Rectangle` class, with a `float` width and height, and a `PatientInformation` class, with a `float` height and weight. Would you really want the compiler to invisibly convert that, if you passed the wrong type?

Note that the following code will work fine:

```
int main()
{
    vector2d vec = {100, 100};
    drawpoint(reinterpret_cast<point2d const&>(vec));
}
```

Still, the appropriate solution here is to just be cleaner with your use of types. It does not make *sense* for a vector to be passed to `drawpoint`, any more than it would make sense for a point to be passed to `moveBy`. Think in terms of types, not in terms of members.

Comment: You are right, I dont want willy nilly conversions, but something like: drawpoint((point2d) vec); might be a next best thing?

Answer (score 1):

```
point2d pnt;
memcpy(&pnt, &vec, sizeof(pnt));
drawpoint(pnt);
```

or

```
point2d pnt = { vec.x, vec.y };
drawpoint(pnt);
```

or

```
drawpoint(point2d{vec.x, vec.y});
```

or

```
drawpoint(*(const point2d*)&vec); // UB, but will work on many implementations
```

Comment: Thanks, that 3rd one looks quite satisfying.

Answer (score 0):

You can't, you have to thing like this:

```
void main
{
vector2d vec = {100, 100};

point2d p;
p.x = vec.x;
p.y = vec.y;

Drawpoint(p);

}
```

Comment: I suppose another question then is, is the compiler going to catch that identical types are being passed and skip the stack temp variable transfer part altogether?  I mean, the compiler can see those types are identical.

Comment: @KayOL78: your function passes the argument by value, so it must do a copy, be it the same or a different type. If you pass by reference then the last sample from my post is the only one that will not result in a temporary, but it involves undefined behavior (specifically on implementations with strict-aliasing rules).

Comment: Yes, it does.  But the code with manual swap involving stack variable would imply two swaps?  And with small types I try not to use references as I have heard they are more efficient and when they are not the compiler will usually change those ones to ref&

Answer (score 0):

you have a bunch of small syntax issues, did you try to compile this.

```
  Struct, Void, and Float
```

should not be capitalize

```
  Void main
```

should be 
      int main()

but most importantly you have defined Drawpoint() to take a Vector2D as a parameter and you are trying to pass it a point2d. C++ is type safe and wont let you just substitute one type for another.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a base class:

```
struct XY{
  float x;
  float y;
};
```

then

```
struct vector2D: XY{
};

struct point2D: XY{
};

void drawPoint(XY& xy){
}
```